# is tangle (IoTA) Depth-first search or Breadth-first search?

Tags: iota-network, tangle, attach-to-tangle, dag, iota-cli

There is several of algorithms for topology sorting for DAG. What is algorithm used by tangle for search, is it Depth-first search or Breadth-first search or is there another method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the tip selection algorithm searches for transactions, it uses a depth parameter.

You can find out more about depth here: https://docs.iota.org/docs/getting-started/0.1/transactions/depth